# Django code behaving differently on local and server

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

This is an old question I never got a satisfactory answer for and I have decided to add a bounty here so that someone might take an interest and figure out what is going on.

**The below code works fine locally but when I deploy it to the server I keep getting the below error.** I believe the issue is that there is no value at the position `images[1]` when the code is run. However I don't understand why this only happens on the server and not on my local machine.

- **Local:** OS X 10.9.5, Python 2.7.5, Django 1.6.2
- **Server:** Ubuntu 12.04, Apache 2.2.22, mod_wsgi Version: 3.3-4ubuntu0.1, Python 2.7.3, Django 1.6

[image: error image]

I have marked `### line 143 ###` below.

[This is related to a previous issue I was having](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27081091/deployed-django-project-giving-list-index-out-of-range-error-local-project-wo) in relation to persisting data from one page to the next in a Django SessionWizardView where it was recommended that I use a session object to store the data I want to persist for use in later pages.

```
images []
PATH_ONE_IMAGES =   ['P1D1.jpg', 'P2D2.jpg', 'P3D3.jpg']


class SurveyWizardOne(SessionWizardView):                      

    def get_context_data(self, form, **kwargs):
        context = super(SurveyWizardOne, self).get_context_data(form, **kwargs)  
        step = int(self.steps.current)

        if step in range (5, 19):

            if step in (5, 6, 7):
                image = random.choice(PATH_ONE_IMAGES)   
                images.insert(step - 5, image)        

                PATH_ONE_IMAGES.remove(image)
                context['display_image'] = image

                if step == 5:
                    self.request.session['first_image'] = images[0] 
                    self.request.session.get('first_image', 'default_request_session_value') 

                elif step == 6:
                    self.request.session['second_image'] = images[1]  ### line 143 ###
                    self.request.session.get('second_image', 'default_request_session_value') 

                elif step == 7:        
                    self.request.session['third_image'] = images[2] 
                    self.request.session.get('third_image', 'default_request_session_value')

            elif step == 8:                 
                slider_value = self.request.POST.get('slider_value')
                if slider_value is not None:
                    slider_DV_values.insert(step - 5, slider_value)  

                context['first_image'] = self.request.session['first_image']
                context['second_image'] = self.request.session['second_image']
                context['third_image'] = self.request.session['third_image']                 
                context['first_slider'] = slider_DV_values[0]  
                context['second_slider'] = slider_DV_values[1]       
                context['third_slider'] = slider_DV_values[2] 


                ....

                ....

        return context
```

If anyone can explain why this error is happening in deployment and not locally and provide a fix it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks, Deepend

Comment: Have you checked that the server receives the session cookie of the client at every request?

Comment: My guess is, images list has only 2 elements in it. Just try using pdb, or print the contents of images to console.

Comment: Hummm, I have not even heard of that. can you tell me how I can go check that? I'm pretty new to Python/Django and coding in general. Thanks

Comment: just `print images` should print a list, or even `print len(images)`

Comment: Print ``request.COOKIES['sessionid']``.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not good at explaining things, but I'll give it a try.

The key problem is because you have `images` list defined globally. It works for you locally since you have a *single process* running under the [local django development server](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#runserver-port-or-address-port). Every request is sharing the same "memory space", accessing the same `images` variable in the same process.

When you deploy your app to the server, you are entering a *multi-process* environment - in simple words, the value of `images` is not shared across multiple processes and, therefore, it is not shared between different requests. In other words, you are inserting into different `images` lists in different requests:

- [Global Variable Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20287213/global-variable-django)
- [python global variable not working in apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3035776/python-global-variable-not-working-in-apache)

Do not use global variables, really, please don't.

To fix the issue you need to keep the `images` somewhere else - inside a session, or in the database:

```
def get_context_data(self, form, **kwargs):
    context = super(SurveyWizardOne, self).get_context_data(form, **kwargs)  
    step = int(self.steps.current)

    images = self.request.session.get('images', [])

    ...

    self.request.session['images'] = images
    return context
```

Comment: That certainly sounds plausible. Unfortunately when I take out the `images []` from the top of the views.py file I keep getting an error "list index out of range" when it gets to the same point (local and on server). Any ideas?

Comment: @Deepend, where are u storing images list now? Please show the code. Thanks.

Comment: I just added the line you suggested above `images = self.request.session.get('images', [])` I thought this would add it to the session. Sorry I am only learning Django. Is there a way I should be adding it to the DB or to the Session?

Comment: @Deepend ok, sure. Make sure you have the other line that sets the value later in the method.

Answer (score 0):

You could add try-except blocks in order to avoid this error to break your view:

```
...

if step == 5:
    try:
        self.request.session['first_image'] = images[0] 
        self.request.session.get('first_image', 'default_request_session_value')
    except IndexError:
        # TODO: do something here to debug instead of passing
        # eg.: import pdb; pdb.set_trace(), so you will be able to debug it in the python console where you ran your app
        pass
elif step == 6:
    try:
        self.request.session['second_image'] = images[1]  ### line 143 ###
        self.request.session.get('second_image', 'default_request_session_value')
    except IndexError:
        # TODO: do something here to debug instead of passing
        # eg.: import pdb; pdb.set_trace(), so you will be able to debug it in the python console where you ran your app
        pass
# and so on

...
```

Hope it gives you a clue to investigate! Good luck!